# Does the output cache work when using webgarden?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

IIS7, WINDOWS WEB SERVER 2008, ASP.NET 4.0
Does the output cache work when using webgarden?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but each garden process will be holding own copy of the cached results.

https://serverfault.com/questions/93730/does-a-worker-process-share-its-output-cache-within-an-apppool